# How do I loop this I/O program successfully?

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, while-loop, io

How do I loop this code so that everything you enter appears in the file "list.txt" successfully and so that you can ask to add another item in order to continue?

This is my prompt if that helps:

> "Write a program that will record the purchases made at a store. For each purchase, read from the keyboard an item’s name, its price, and the number bought. Compute the cost of the purchase (number bought times price), and write all this data to a text file. Also, display this information and the current total cost on the screen. After all items have been entered, write the total cost to both the screen and the file. Since we want to remember all purchases made, you should append new data to the end of the file."

```
package market;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Market 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String fileName = "List.txt";
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try
    {
        outputStream= new PrintWriter (fileName);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file "+ fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
       System.out.println("Problem with input from file "+fileName);
    }
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    double cost;
    double total=0;

    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
         String name = keyboard.next(); 
         int quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
         double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
         cost = quantity*price;
         total += cost;

         System.out.println(quantity + " " + name + " = " + cost);
         System.out.println("Subtotal = " + total);

         outputStream.println(quantity + " " + name + " = " + cost);
         outputStream.println("Cost = " + cost);
         outputStream.println("Subtotal = " + total);
         outputStream.close();


    }
    System.out.println("Would you like another item?");
    System.out.println("Total = " + total);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. You just need some small changes in your code. Specifically, you are checking the boolean variable `done` for the while loop. So, basically you need to modify this variable value based on the user's input in every loop, like so,

```
package market;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Market 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String fileName = "List.txt";
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try
    {
        outputStream= new PrintWriter (fileName);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file "+ fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
       System.out.println("Problem with input from file "+fileName);
    }
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    double cost;
    double total=0;

    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
         String name = keyboard.next(); 
         int quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
         double price = keyboard.nextDouble();
         cost = quantity*price;
         total += cost;

         System.out.println(quantity + " " + name + " = " + cost);
         System.out.println("Subtotal = " + total);

         outputStream.println(quantity + " " + name + " = " + cost);
         outputStream.println("Cost = " + cost);
         outputStream.println("Subtotal = " + total);

         //outputStream.close();
         //don't close the stream till you are totally done. Close this outside the while loop

        //This block of code needs to be inside the loop and not outside 
        System.out.println("Would you like another item?");
        //Modify the done variable here
        done = keyboard.nextLine().equals("Y")?false:true; // if user enters Y, loop continues, else done will be true and the loop won't continue
        System.out.println("Total = " + total);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    outputStream.close();
}

}
```